# How to align two big txt. files line by line and return a third file?

Tags: python

Imagine that I have two files like:

```
'My name is George.'
'I like music.'
'Today I'm going to the beach.'
```

in txt. file 1.

And:

```
'O meu nome é Jorge.' 
'Gosto de música.'
'Hoje vou à praia.'
```

in txt. file 2

I need two join both files in a third file like:

```
'My name is George.'

'O meu nome é Jorge.' 
'I like music.'
'Gosto de música.'
'Today I'm going to the beach.'
'Hoje vou à praia.'
```

Comment: use `zip` on both file handles. `for l1,l2 in zip(f1,f2)`

Comment: I suggest you have a go yourself before asking for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a file's readlines() for that:

```
with open('english.txt', 'r') as input_file:
    english = input_file.readlines()

with open('spanish.txt', 'r') as input_file:
    spanish = input_file.readlines()

with open('combined.txt', 'w') as output_file:
    for i in range(len(english)):
        output_file.write(english[i])
        output_file.write(spanish[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer works, but just proposing a shorter and less memory consuming solution (you mentioned the files are big):

```
with open(filename1, "r") as f1, \ 
         open(filename2, "r") as f2, \
         open(filename3, "w") as f3:
    for l1,l2 in zip(f1,f2):
        f3.write(l1)
        f3.write(l2)
```

This will load only one line at a time (instead of all the files) to memory.